# Sending response of multiple api calls from action to view file in react js with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am beginner to React JS and Redux and have got stuck in a problem. I have to call a login api and if that return success I need to call another api using axios to get user details. Following is my function in action doing it:

```
 export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
  return AuthServicee.login(username, password).then(
    (data) => {
      if(data.success) {
        userService.getUserDetails(username).then((data) => {
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data.data));
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: { user: data },
          });
          return Promise.resolve();
        },(error) => {
          const message =
          (error.response &&
            error.response.data &&
            error.response.data.message) ||
          error.message ||
          error.toString();
  
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL,
          });
  
          dispatch({
            type: SET_MESSAGE,
            payload: message,
          });
  
          return Promise.reject();
        }).catch(err => {
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL,
          });
        });;   
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_FAIL,
        });
        dispatch({
          type: SET_MESSAGE,
          payload: data.error,
        });
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      });

      dispatch({
        type: SET_MESSAGE,
        payload: message,
      });

      return Promise.reject();
    }
  );
};
```

I am calling the above function from my login page as following:

```
const handleLogin = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
setLoading(true);
form.current.validateAll();
if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
  dispatch(login(username, password))
    .then(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      if (props !=null && props.isAuthenticated) {
        props.history.push("/home");
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
} else {
  setLoading(false);
}
```

};

Now since I have return with the first API call, it returns data as soon as the first API provides a response and does not wait for the second call to finish. It should wait till both API calls are finished and then return the result to Login.js.
Can someone please help me here?
**Working Solution as per cb dev answer**

```
    const login = async (username, password) => {
      try {
        const loginRes = await loginUser(username, password);
        if (loginRes.data != null && loginRes.data.success) {
          localStorage.setItem("access_token", loginRes.data.data);
          const getUserRes = await getUserDetail(loginRes.data.data, username);
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(getUserRes.data));
          return getUserRes.data;
        } else {
          return loginRes.data;
        }
      }catch (err) {
          console.log("Something went wrong with the login process...");
          console.log(`I can log the error here: ${err}`);
        }
    }
function loginUser(username, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const response = axios
    .post(API_URL + "users/authenticate", {
      username,
      password,
    });
    resolve(response);
  });
}

function getUserDetail(access_token, username) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Login_step2: I've got ${access_token}...`);
    var url = apiConfig.API_BASE_URL + "users?username="+username;
    resolve (axios.get(url, { headers: authHeader() }));
  });
}
```

Comment: Does the second API call depend on the first one?

Comment: yes I get token from first api call, and then use it in second api to get details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `async-await` syntax. It will make your code much nicer to read and will be a lot easier to control the behavior you're intending.

https://javascript.info/async-await

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Something like this:

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-brattain-pm0pj)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function mockLogin_step1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Login_step1 success"), 1000);
  });
}

function mockLogin_step2(something) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Login_step2: I've got ${something}...`);
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Login_step2 success"), 1000);
  });
}

function App() {
  async function doLogin() {
    try {
      console.log("Calling async API login STEP 1");
      const step1Result = await mockLogin_step1();
      console.log(step1Result);
      console.log("Calling async API login STEP 2");
      const step2Result = await mockLogin_step2("something from step1");
      console.log(step2Result);
      console.log("I can dispatch something here...");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Something went wrong with the login process...");
      console.log("An error probably happened on step1 or step2...");
      console.log(`I can log the error here: ${err}`);
      console.log("I can dispatch something here...");
    }
  }

  return <button onClick={doLogin}>Login</button>;
}

export default App;
```

The resulting log:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, cddeveloper, I followed the approach shared by you and it worked. I have posted my updated function in the question as a solution